# Where is the "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests" option?

Tags: github

The [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) say there should be an option to allow specific actors to bypass required pull requests:
[image]

I need this for CI, which commits version updates automatically on the master branch. However other admin users should still have to go through PR process.

But this option isn't showing in GitHub:
[image]

How do I get this option to display?

Comment: I see this option in a public test repository. Is this repository privet since that may be the cause.

Comment: This is a public repo that I am the owner of. Nothing special about it that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

I believe this option is limited for repositories in organizations.